# Remove page from navigation stack

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I navigate from page A to page B and when I hit the back button, I don't want to return to page A. 
How can I remove the page from the navigation stack?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
public navCtrl: NavController,
```

You can use [remove](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#remove)

```
this.navCtrl.push(page3).then(() => {
  let index = 1;
  this.navCtrl.remove(index);
});
```